# creating labels and index for already existed nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

We are using `Neo4j 2.0.0.M05`, i just searched for creating labels and index for already existed bulk of nodes, didnt get perfect answer.

we are using node_auto_index property, but fetching is very slow ,how can we create Labels and Indexes for Bulk of Existing nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.0, the indexes are easy to create in Cypher:

```
CREATE INDEX on :Label(property);
```

It will go and populate the index with current nodes that have the :Label label.

Then you query with the label again:

```
MATCH (n:Label) 
WHERE n.property = "..." 
RETURN n;
```

Comment: thanks freeman for replying,but..i have to create Labels also..you are saying creating indexes using label propery..i didnt created labels..

Comment: You set a label with `SET n :Label`, see here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-set.html#set-set-a-label-on-a-node  If the label doesn't already exist it's created.

Comment: @jjaderberg i tried to create label's as you suggested.in my db we are having nearly 1.8 Lakhs nodes.its taking too much amount of time,how to resolve the thing..?